# How to use states to change the value of one input field based on what is entered in another in REACT FINAL FORM?

Tags: reactjs, react-final-form

I want to know how can I add states to my final form function to change the value of one input field based on the value entered in another and can it be done in any other way?

Here is the Final Form Code,

I want to display the end date based on the number of nights and the start date entered. I have highlighted it in the code as well.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Form as FinalForm } from 'react-final-form';

const EditDescriptionFormComponent = props => {
  return (
    <FinalForm
      {...props}
      mutators={{ ...arrayMutators }}
      render={formRenderProps => {
        const {
          className,
          disabled,
          ready,
          handleSubmit,
          invalid,
          pristine,
          updated,
          updateInProgress,
          fetchErrors,
          filterConfig,
        } = formRenderProps;

        const classes = classNames(css.root, className);
        const submitReady = (updated && pristine) || ready;
        const submitInProgress = updateInProgress;
        const submitDisabled = invalid || disabled || submitInProgress;

        return (
          <Form className={classes} id={css.formSection} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <FieldTextInput
                  id="startDate"
                  name="startDate"
                  type="date"
                  min={new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0]}
                />
                <FieldTextInput
                  id="nights"
                  name="nights"
                  type="number"
                  min="0"
                />

                <FieldTextInput
                  className={css.field}
                  type="number"
                  label="End Date"
                  disabled
                />                            {/*I want to show the end date calculated from the start date and the number of nights here*/}

            <Button
              type="submit"
              inProgress={submitInProgress}
              disabled={submitDisabled}
              ready={submitReady}
            >
              SAVE
            </Button>
          </Form>
        );
      }}
    />
  );
};


export default compose(EditDescriptionFormComponent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this pretty much what the [Calculated Fields](https://codesandbox.io/s/oq52p6v96y) example is doing?